# If person got covid vaccine some time ago, should he get flu vaccine?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, influenza

Say person got covid vaccine several months ago (say one of Chinese vaccines),
is it safe to get flu vaccine?

Best info I found was from [CDC](https://www.cdc.gov/flu/season/faq-flu-season-2021-2022.htm)

> While limited data exist on giving COVID-19 vaccines with other
> vaccines, including flu vaccines, experience with giving other
> vaccines **together** has shown the way our bodies develop protection and
> possible side effects are generally similar whether vaccines are given
> alone or with other vaccines.

But this is answer to a question about getting those vaccines **together (at the same time)**.

I am not sure how different the answer is if person was already vaccinated against covid several months ago?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is safe and highly recommended to get a flu vaccine, with at least two weeks between getting a COVID vaccine (of any kind) and the flu vaccine, as mentioned [here](https://www.newsobserver.com/news/coronavirus/article248692250.html):

> And the Centers for Disease Control and Prevention advises that the flu vaccine is more important than ever this year, because it not only protects you and the people around you from getting the flu, but fewer cases of the flu also “help reduce the strain on healthcare systems responding to the COVID-19 pandemic.”

> But if you do plan to get the flu shot, Weber says that shot (and any other vaccines) **should be separated by at least two weeks**, per CDC recommendations.

Comment: CDC apparently has updated their recommendations and no longer suggests any interval.

Answer (score 1):

You've answered your own question:

> ...the way our bodies develop protection and possible side effects are
> generally similar whether vaccines are given alone ...

"Alone" (i.e. not at the same time) is what you're asking about.

Regarding vaccines given together at the same time, that's OK too.  According to an updated news story, the CDC has updated its recommendation and no longer recommends getting different vaccines two weeks apart:

> Will the flu shot interfere in any way with the COVID vaccine?
>
> Skariah: “No, it should not interfere in any way with the COVID
> vaccine.
>
> “In the past, the CDC had recommended waiting 14 days between COVID
> vaccines and any other vaccines but now they feel this is unnecessary
> based on the evidence.”

Read more [here](https://www.newsobserver.com/news/local/article253389783.html):